# React i18next: Are there drawbacks to calling i18n.init twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

I have a React Native app in which I init i18n with a local translation file. Then I fetch a remote translation file and re-init i18n with that. This remote file is more up to date, and could contain typo fixes or missing strings that were not in the local file, for example.

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

export const initializeI18n = translations => i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources: translations,
    // ... other init options
  })
```

I first call `initializeI18n` with the local file to optimize app startup time (don't depend on a network request), and shortly after I call it again with the fetched remote file.

This is working totally fine but since the [react-i18next docs](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-after-init) don't suggest this method to add translations after init, I am wondering if this method has drawbacks I don't see yet.

Any advice or recommendations greatly appreciated. Thx!

Comment: why not use the `addResourceBundle`? init is probably more cpu intensive than this method.

Comment: It is necessary to `init` i18n on app start. I guess I could init with empty `resources` and `addResourceBundle` later if I needed to optimize resource load time, but that is not my question. My question is: are there drawbacks to calling `init` twice (or more times).

Comment: init is probably more cpu intensive than this method then addResourceBundle